# How are progressive quotients written?

Tags: group-theory, notation, quotient-group

Let $W=X/Y$ be a quotient of $X$

Let $W/Z$ be a quotient of $W$

To write $W/Z$ without $W$, Would we need to write $(X/Y)/Z$?  I presume $X/Y/Z$ is ambiguous?

I'm imagining a group quotient and not assuming this is necessarily the same or different for other types of quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one would write $(X/Y)/Z$.

However, note that this implies that $Z$ is a normal subgroup of $W$, and thus since $W$ is a quotient group of $X$ we may identify $Z = \pi(K)$ where $K$ is a normal subgroup of $X$, $Y \subseteq K$, $\pi: X \rightarrow X/Y = W$ is the canonical projection. Then by the third iso theorem we have

$$(X/Y) /Z = (X/Y)/(K/Y) = X/K ~~.$$

Comment: Thanks. Does this generalise beyond groups?  e.g. monoids, sets, other objects?

Comment: For rings and modules, this works quite the same. Something similar can be said about universal algebras, though the theorem may not be quite as clean as it is for groups and rings. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#General) for the most general setting.